# Are Jobs tears (coix seed) kitniyot?

Tags: halacha, passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

I have run across a seed called [Job’s tears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job's_tears). Anybody know if this would be considered Kitniyot?

Some brands are certified kosher. Would this need a special hechsher for Pesach? A Rabbi from a prominent kashrut organization claimed it was. Yet, he cited no evidence.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please take a look at our [tour] for some useful information about the site. Thank you for bringing this intriguing question here!

Answer (score 6):

There appears to have been no particular custom against them.

When the Star-K came out strongly arguing that quinoa was not kitniyos, I'd heard that there was talk of then certifying other semi-grains about which there was no custom, such as Job's tears (or teff, for that matter). Instead there was strong opposition to quinoa, so the Star-K stopped there. At least that's the way I heard it.

That doesn't mean it's not kitniyos; it means that no major US kashrus organization has publicly gone out and called it "kosher l'Pesach for Ashkenazim."

Some have interpreted kitniyos as a categorical ban that would include plants unbeknownst to our Ashkenazic ancestors if they meet certain criteria; if so, one could argue that newly-identified semi-grains are included.

Rabbi Moshe Feinstein zt'l wrote in [Igros Moshe OC3:63](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=366) that there was no categorical ban; what makes something kitniyos? Only if a custom developed about it. He also suggested that they stopped adding things to the blacklist or else there would be nothing left to eat! One of Rav Moshe's proofs is -- why for 500 years was mustard prohibited and caraway allowed; which of those two would you more logically expect to be cross-contaminated or confused with wheat?

The plain reading of Rav Moshe's responsum (addressing peanuts, actually) would indicate that Job's tears should be permitted.

Those reading kitniyos as a categorical ban would disagree; some even claimed that Rav Moshe would agree quinoa is kitniyos because it is so absolutely, clearly a grain ... therefore some would prohibit.

Lastly, this is all a moot point if we can't identify a production of these seeds that we are confident were not cross-contaminated with wheat or barley. On that question, you'd have to consult someone who knows the food industry well.

Comment: Since Job’s tears are marketed strongly as gluten free, and some are certified as such. Less than 20ppm. I would say that should be enough to cross threshold of no grain contamination. Therefore, according to Rav Moshe’s ruling, Job’s tears should be allowed.

Answer (score 4):

The OU doesn't list Job's tears or coix seed on their list of [kitnyiot](https://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/food-items/kitniyot-list/) products, but they list millet (and Wiki says Job's tears are also called adlay - or adlay millet - but it appears to be a different species).

There is controversy whether beans and grains that became popular recently (e.g., sunflower seeds, string beans, peanuts and quinoa) are included or not in the prohibition of *kitniot*. Some hold that they are, others that they are not. R Aharon E Marcus (in his book [Halacha 24/7/12](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9655722341) p. 243) writes R Moshe Feinstein held they are not.

Both of these could be reason enough to consider Jobs' tears not *kitniot* but you should ask your own rav if this is relevant to you in practice.